# How can I add a marker using SymbolOptions in MapBoxMapController

Tags: flutter, mapbox

I'm working on a project for my studies and I'm using Flutter and I choose mapbox to add a Map on it.
I've found a solution but the problem now is I dont know how to add a marker using an icon and title
Please anyy help
My code is showing below

```
    Card(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            const Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 12.0),
              child: Text('This is a map.'),
            ),
            Center(
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 300.0,
                height: 300.0,
                child: MapboxMap(
                  onMapCreated: onMapCreated,
                  initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                    target: center,
                    zoom: 11.0,
                  ),
                  gestureRecognizers:
                      <Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>>[
                    Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>(
                      () => EagerGestureRecognizer(),
                    ),
                  ].toSet(),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

Comment: void onMapCreated(MapboxMapController controller) {
    controller.addSymbol(SymbolOptions(
        geometry: LatLng(
          center.latitude,
          center.longitude,
        ),

        iconImage: "airport-15"));
    controller.addLine(
      LineOptions(
        geometry: [
          LatLng(-33.86711, 151.1947171),
          LatLng(-33.86711, 151.1947171),
          LatLng(-32.86711, 151.1947171),
          LatLng(-33.86711, 152.1947171),
        ],
        lineColor: "#ff0000",
        lineWidth: 7.0,
        lineOpacity: 0.5,
      ),
    );
  }

Comment: Example of a symbol can be seen in https://github.com/tobrun/flutter-mapbox-gl/blob/master/example/lib/place_symbol.dart note that custom icon support is still under development. You can only reference icons found in the style spritesheet for now.